# Is this an anti pattern or misusing the interface default method?

Tags: java, exceptions, patterns-and-practices, null, default-method

Instead of checking the null and throwing exception each time we call `findByOrderNumber` method, I came up with this pattern by taking advantage of a default method, are there any patterns misused here or is it considered as misusing the default methods?

```java
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, UUID> {

  
    Optional<Order> findByOrderNumber(@NotBlank String orderNumber);

    default Order findByOrderNumber_NullSafe(@NotBlank String orderNumber) throws ApiCustomErrorsException {
        return findByOrderNumber(orderNumber)
                .orElseThrow(()-> new ApiCustomErrorsException("Order not found"));
    }
}
```

### **Update**

On the client side

```java
final Order order = orderRepository.findByOrderNumber(orderNumber)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ApiCustomErrorsException("Order not found"));

//changed to 

final Order order = orderRepository.findByOrderNumber_NullSafe(orderNumber);
```

On the client side each time I call `orderRepository.findByOrderNumber` I used to check the optional for empty. With the modified code I can assure that `findByOrderNumber_NullSafe` will not return null.

Comment: Can you add a code sample of how to call this method, and how you used to call it when you needed to check for null?

Comment: I think you have got confused between *null* and an *empty Optional*. You are not checking for null anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if it's an anti-pattern as such but I wouldn't do it that way for a couple of reasons:

- Optional exists precisely to help with these null checks. You are telling the caller that the value may be null so they should check before using it. Adding another check on top seems redundant.
- You now have 2 public methods on the interface with different names but you only want the second one to be used. I would find this confusing if I came to use this interface.

I am thinking primarily of other developers; the least surprising way to code this is simply returning the Optional from the interface in the usual way. This is likely to be easier to understand and maintain going forwards.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an abuse of `default` methods.  It depends on nothing other than the interface definition itself and your approach is going to reduce the duplication of code.  Optionals have a clear benefit but Java code that uses them tends to look like vomit.  This is a pragmatic way to use them and maintain readability.

The only things I would change about this is your naming strategy.  If this is method that is more commonly used, I would make it `findByOrderNumber` and name the optional version something like `optionallyFindByOrderNumber`.

Comment: if I remember correctly, the `Optional<T> findBy...` is is really required due to automatic JPA repository implementation that happens at runtime (SQL query is generated based on the fields used after the prefix and so on), so regarding the naming strategy for the non-optional method, maybe simply `getBy...` is simple/direct enough, while  `findBy...` remains for the optional case.

Answer (score 1):

> On the client side each time I call orderRepository.findByOrderNumber I used to check the optional for null.

I think you have got confused between *null* and an *empty Optional*. If `findByOrderNumber` returns a *null*, then you would get a NullPointerException in both versions of the code. I think you meant an Optional that is empty.

I would not say this is an anti-pattern or abuse. It is subjective. I wouldn't be surprised if an interface offered two methods - one returning an Optional and other throwing an exception.

You could rename the methods better.

- `findByOrderNumber` - to throw an exception if order does not exist
- `tryFindByOrderNumber` - returns an Optional

This requires changing all existing callers which is a call you have to take.

Answer (score 1):

It is fundamentally problematic because the exceptionality of not having an order with a given number is based on the use case. Let's pretend that you aren't even using `Optional`, and consider these two use cases:

Use case 1 (non-exceptional):

```
public boolean orderExists(String number) {
    return findByOrderNumber(orderNumber) != null;
}
```

Use case 2 (exceptional):

```
public void submitOrder(String number) {
    Order order = findByOrderNumber(orderNumber); // May return null
    order.submit(); // May throw NPE
}
```

The solution for this is to use `Optional`, which you are already doing. Creating a null-safe version of a method that already returns an `Optional` is, as others mentioned, redundant. The above examples could be rewritten as follows:

Use case 1 (non-exceptional):

```
public boolean orderExists(String number) {
    return findByOrderNumber(orderNumber).isPresent();
}
```

Use case 2A (ignore missing orders):

```
public void submitOrder(String number) {
    Optional<Order> order = findByOrderNumber(orderNumber);
    order.ifPresent(Order::submit);
}
```

Use case 2B (throw on missing orders):

```
public void submitOrder(String number) {
    Order order = findByOrderNumber(orderNumber).get(); // Will throw if missing
    order.submit();
}
```

You might correctly assume that the `Optional` itself could also be null. Unfortunately, Java has no built-in solution for that. One good way to mitigate that is with coding standards. For example, you can decide, as a team, that you will never return `null` from any method. I find that most of the controversy surrounding `NullPointerException` issues is deciding whether or not it *should* have been null, or if we just *should* have checked first.

Answer (score 0):

> On the client side each time I call orderRepository.findByOrderNumber I used to check the optional for empty. With the modified code I can assure that findByOrderNumber_NullSafe will not return null.

So, you will still be breaking the client's code path, only in a *different* way. It is effectively **the same thing** you are achieving there, only now, you provide **two ways to fail instead of just one** and in one of them, **you are making a decision in their place**. I strongly disagree with your "NullSafe" approach, for various reasons, the first and foremost being that **it is not really "null-safe"**.

## Short Answer

[Dan Saunders really sums it up best](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/411983/340885).
You don't really gain anything using this default method, you are not trying to maintain backward compatibility, neither are you looking for a functional interface. You are not gaining actual expressive power there, on the contrary, you are making it more complicated and confusing. Someone will need to try to *interpret* these things and they are going to spend more time than is necessary to understand. This is, usually, bad.

## Long Answer

Null-safety is the virtue of **preventing the breaking of a code path in the case of a null pointer (i.e. empty variable)**. Your `Optional` provides a means to achieve **just that**, i.e. in case you find nothing, you **communicate** that fact to the client, rather than just send back `**nothing**` (emphatically), and let the client discover this through an `Exception`. The client is, then, not obliged to find out your value could be null through trial-and-error, or by reading your instructions. Don't give your client instructions, **guide them**.

It looks as if you are on both sides of this service-client API. You see, when you are both the service **and** the client developer, you are designing the service the way **you** would like to use it as your own client. You **know** what to expect because it's **you** that is writing the service, so sometimes, you get more inventive with things, and sometimes carried away with your inventions. Let me tell you a little story, though, of a **real client of your API**... a client that really knows **absolutely nothing** regarding what's behind the API.

They encounter 2 methods, and start wondering... they have to look for instructions or comments, documentation and such things. Hmmm, why `default`? There must be some reason... They decide to go with the method that has `NullSafe` in its name, makes them feel *safe* anyhow. The other one is still tempting because it seems to be clear in what it returns: **possibly an `Order`**, but null-safety sounds *cool* so you, indirectly, convinced half of your clients, and this one belongs to the "convinced" half.

Eventually, they begin to think, how can this other method be null-safe when it always returns an `Order`? As they are going to find out, they get a beautiful `Exception` when there is no `Order`. OK, they think whoever made the service meant to protect their code from going further, at all costs. They feel slightly bad because what happens **conceptually** is that instead of **them themselves** deciding when their code path would break, **someone else is making that decision instead**.

So, they have to use a try-catch block, they really **cannot do otherwise**, because they don't really want to crash their applications. Do they have any use for the entire call stack at that point? Are there many reasons to fail, or just one (namely that no order exists)? They `try-catch` and just throw the exception away. Or they systematically log it, only to find out that there really is only one reason, *Order not found*. After all this, they just go back and change it all to use the `Optional` because they really **do not want a meaningless call stack snapshot** because **they know the call stack at that point anyway** and they know which `orderNumber` they were looking for, so they have everything they need to report back to the user the very simple fact that (as an empty optional clearly conveys) the requested order number is just *not available*.

It's usually like that... or they just use the `Optional` method, which is clearer.

The worst part is that the two methods are **identical** and you are not really gaining anything from having them both at the same time. Your discomfort that stems from the sometimes repetitive task of checking whether an `Optional` is empty is mostly **unwarranted**. This is the precise reason they were made for: *to make it explicit that some values **might simply not exist***. So instead of an **unexpected** `Exception` that someone would eventually get **despite your best intentions in documenting all the different `Exception`s your methods throw**, handing them an `Optional` is like saying in their face: "Look, I don't know how much simpler to put it, **this value might not exist**".

As far as valid usage is concerned, fair reasons to *break* external code through exceptions might be when you really **can not do anything else** or there are **multiple reasons to break** and you don't really want to use a lame enumeration to report failure reasons, because you get to keep the API cleaner and more concise. Plus you really do want to wrap the entire call stack because **it will really mean something to the caller**, depending on the case.